# How to create a multilingual url in htaccess by adding the display language as a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess

For a website that I have locally, I need to update in multilingual mode a code snippet for setting the display language.

First of all I need the system to make sure that the url has been typed with the language; if not, it will have to convert the url with the default language, adding it as a subfolder.

Finally, the system should check which display language has been chosen and automatically add it to the query => `&lang=(language)`

I have tried this code but it does not work.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(en|de|fr)/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /test/en/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/$ /test/index.php?lang=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/city/(.+?)$ city.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/(.*)$ /test/$1 [L]
```

The pattern (en|de|fr) in server side language always works. I don't understand why it doesn't work in HTACCESS.

**SOLVED**

I think I have solved it. Now, if I type `local_ip/test/en` (without the final slash) the system correctly directs me to `local_ip/test/en/` (with the final slash).

Here is just the code of interest.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /(en|de|fr)$ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /test/%1/ [R,L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(en|de|fr)/ [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) /test/en/$1 [R,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/$ /test/index.php?lang=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your efforts, could you please do mention which sample url is not working for you? And what is the error you are getting?

Comment: For example, if I type `local_ip/test/en`, the system converts the url to `local_ip/test/en/en` . I think this is an error in the pattern.

Comment: yea, your rules not having that kind of conditions. Could you please do add samples like FROM which url TO which url you want to redirect or rewrite? That will help us to understand question more, cheers.

Comment: I need the system to recognise the language to be displayed whether I type `local_ip/test/(en|de|fr)/` or `local_ip/test/(en|de|fr)`. So both with the final '/' and without.

Comment: I am sorry but still not clear. if you could give like: `http://localhost:80/en/test`(as an example) should redirect to `http://localhost:80/en/en/test`(again sample url) with either they should redirect in browser too or not? If you could give this kind of question then it will be helpful, thank you.

Comment: No. If I type `local_ip/test` the system doesn't recognise the language choice and correctly directs me to the default language, i.e. `local_ip/test/en/`. But if I type `local_ip/test/en` without the final slash, it converts the final url to a double language, i.e. `local_ip/test/en/en` . I need to be able to type `local_ip/test/en`,`local_ip/test/de`, `local_ip/test/fr` (i.e. without the final slash) and be directed to `local_ip/test/en/`, `local_ip/test/de/`, `local_ip/test/fr/` (with the final slash). Is this clearer?

Comment: Ok, so you want to hit links like `local_ip/test/en` OR `local_ip/test/en/` with/without slashes, how about from which files it should get served from backend server? Like: any php file or html file etc? Does it also require to pass query string? Kindly provide these details which will help for better understanding, thank you.

Comment: In short, whether I type `/en` or `/en/`, the system must point me to `/en/` (with the trailing slash).
Whether I type `/de` or `/de/`, the system must direct me to `/de/` (with the trailing slash). Whether I type `/fr` or `/fr/`, the system must redirect me to `/fr/` (with a trailing slash).

Comment: The problem is here: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(en|de|fr)/ [NC]`.

Answer (score 2):

With your shown samples, could you please try following. Place it in root directory of yours, also please clear browser cache before testing your URLs.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} 200
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/(en|de|fr) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /test/en/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/?$ /test/index.php?lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/city/(.+?)/?$ city.php?url=$2&lang=$1 [QSA,NC,L]
RewriteRule ^(en|de|fr)/([^/]*)/?$ /test/$1 [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: @webdevfp, it's very late night here may be we could work on this one tomorrow morning cheers

Comment: I think I have solved it because the tests work. I will update the post with the solution.